# Nissan Cube 2013 tensioner replacement

Tags: nissan, pulley, tensioner

I need to replace the tensioner on my 2013 Nissan Cube. What tools would work best to do this job? I'm having trouble removing the old tensioner because it's in such a tight space. I believe it's a torx bit as well. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you talking about the serpentine belt tensioner or the tensioner on the timing belt?

Comment: A photo or two would be really helpful.